# How to Eliminate the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the angular client side?

Tags: angularjs

After the form submission to the the page redirect into payment gateway page.
after success or failure the page will redirect into the corresponding page like
/success or /failure

script

```
 $http({
          url: "https://secure.payu.in/_payment",
          method: "GET",
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data)
                 console.log(status)
           }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                    console.log(status)
           });
$scope.payemntProceed=function(checkout){
$scope.payment.txnid=Math.floor(100000000000+(Math.random()*900000000000));
$scope.payment.salt="HseUIoSb"
$scope.payment.key="WHlKGc";
$scope.payment.amount=1;
$scope.payment.productinfo=$rootScope.cartlist
$scope.payment.firstname=$rootScope.userinfo.name;
$scope.payment.email=$rootScope.userinfo.email
$scope.payment.phone=$rootScope.userinfo.contactno;
$scope.payment.surl="http://localhost/august1stZustshop/#/home"
$scope.payment.furl="http://localhost/august1stZustshop/#/checkout"
$scope.payment.service_provider="payu_paisa"
var string = $scope.payment.key + '|' + $scope.payment.txnid + '|' + $scope.payment.amount + '|' + $scope.payment.productinfo + '|' + $scope.payment.firstname + '|' + $scope.payment.email + '|||||||||||' + $scope.payment.salt;
$scope.payment.hash = $scope.SHA512(string);
}
```

console shows like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://secure.payu.in/_payment.
No 'Access-   Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
status is -1.
```

It always Executing the failure code.Displaying the status is -1.

form.html

```
<form action="https://secure.payu.in/_payment" method="post" ng-submit="payemntProceed(checkout)">
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.txnid"  name="txnid" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.key"  name="key" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.amount"  name="amount" >       
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.productinfo"  name="productinfo" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.firstname" name="firstname" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.email"  name="email" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.phone"  name="phone" >         
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.hash" name="hash" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.surl"  name="surl" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.furl"  name="furl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="payment.service_provider"  name="service_provider">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
```

please tell me how to remove cross-Origin problem.i am using the payu-money payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stop an XHR cross-origin error from the client side, while still making the request, is to not use XHR.

Get rid of the JavaScript which calls `$http` and submit the form normally.

Comment: please provide article or link.

Comment: @SrinivasAppQube — Why do you need an article in order to stop doing something you've already done?

Comment: i am using normal submit the page cannot redirect to the payment gateway?

Comment: @SrinivasAppQube — You aren't using a normal submit. You are running some JavaScript then using the $http function to do it.

Comment: It's like yours … but without the JavaScript.

Comment: is it possible 302 status with normal submit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118814/discussion-between-srinivasappqube-and-quentin).

Answer (score 0):

https://secure.payu.in/_payment accept POST method with normal form submit.